# Send email messages after comment was submitted

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, email, comment-form, notifications

I need to send 2 email messages: if comment was submitted and when comment was approved. Without any plugin of course. How can I do this?

Comment: For comment approved, you can review this question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59894/approve-comment-hook

Comment: For comment submitted, you can hook into the `comment_post` hook, which you can see here with an example https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_post/

Comment: Thanks czerspalace, you save me one time) Write it as an answer, I will approve it! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comment approved, you can review this question

[Approve comment hook?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59894/approve-comment-hook)

For comment submitted, you can hook into the `comment_post` hook, like

```
function show_message_function( $comment_ID, $comment_approved ) {
    if( 0 === $comment_approved ){
        //function logic goes here
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'show_message_function', 10, 2 );
```

Code copied from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_post/

Comment: Hi czerspalace, really need your help here - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232845/plugin-translations-problem