# Plugin translations problem

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, translation, plugin-qtranslate

I developed a plugin for my client in english by default. I created estonian and russian translation files. But my client installed wordpress with estonian language by default and now, **when my plugin is activated it doesn't use estonian translation file, because I guess wordpress uses estonian language by default.** Russian language works well.  
Client uses qtranslate-x plugin for translations. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Please elaborate on how translations are set up in your plugin. Logically if estonian language files are properly set up then that's exactly what estonian install of WP should use.

Comment: My plugin's text domain is "kvkoolitus". Both translation files named like this: kvkoolitus-et_EE.mo and kvkoolitus-ru_RU.mo. If russian is selected, plugin displays russian words, but when I switch back to estonian - I see only english words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not confident without downloading Estonian copy of WP source, but from look at GlotPress it seems that locale code for it is [simply `et`](https://translate.wordpress.org/locale/et), not `et_EE`.